# Chrome extension + webview

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I'm struggling to find a definitive answer to this.

Chrome Apps are being deprecated across all OS except Chrome OS.

<webview> is only available in Chrome Apps?

This means I can't or shouldn't use <webview> in an extension (if possible)?

Comment: Chrome Apps =/= Chrome Extensions

Comment: You can't use webview in extensions.

Answer (score 6):

As per further research, testing, and comments:

<webview> are definitely not useable in extensions, only in Apps.

Comment: But this really makes no sense, because on google's extensions page it says: "Warning: Starting in version 57, Chrome will no longer allow external web content (including embedded frames and scripts) inside sandboxed pages. Please use a webview instead." - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox . And if you try to include webview in extension manifest file, you get error message saying that webview is supported only in apps.

Comment: I spent some time debugging only because I didn't get an error message like yours. My error message was: You do not have permission to use the webview element. Be sure to declare the "webview" permission in your manifest file.

Comment: @liz or anybody else reading this get a webview to work in an extension?