# Chrome Extension, Not compatible with PC but compatible with Chromebook. How to change it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension and it says its only compatible with chromebook. How can I change it so it works on all devices or so you can purchase on pc and download on chromebook?

Comment: If it's in fact an app, not an extension, then you can't. Post the manifest.

Comment: @JoshLee Here is all of the code- https://github.com/samlanning/leaf-browser                   How can I convert it into an extension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274744/chrome-extension-webview

Comment: @JoshLee So, using the web view command wont work as an extension? How could I change it? Not that familiar with this.